# How to get a single item(id) from search table? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, search, crud

I only need id data from a table for an insert data for another table. But I don't know how?
So I created search data request

```
$iduser = User::where('username','like','%' . request('username') . '%')->get();
```

I can't use $iduser->id or some similar caliber for getting id for that particular data because I get error despite there's an id on database

> property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

Comment: You're using `->get()` and as the error is telling you that returns a collection. Iterate over it or use `->first()`

Comment: Without the get() it still "property [id] does not exist on this collection instance" but I will try again when I boot up my laptop again.

Comment: Well, it's still a collection according to the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get() method will return an Eloquent Collection even you only have one result, you can use the first() method to get one object.

So you should be able to get the id this way:

```
$iduser = User::where('username','like','%' . request('username') . '%')->first()->id;
```

Don't hesitate to use dd() on your variable to see what is the type and the content of the variable.

Comment: It's working as I use this

Answer (score 0):

You have a collection of Users. If you were to loop through them;

```
foreach($iduser as $user){
var_dump($user->id);
}
```

Or, if you pass the collection to the view, you can loop through it there and access it's ID.

Comment: "_property [id] does not exist on this collection instance_" It's a collection. Not a single item.

Comment: So all I need to do is add primary key to the models?

Comment: Sorry @TheBetweener I misunderstood your question. I'd add it anyway just for good practice, but also check my updated answer. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Well all I need is just a single item

Comment: Change ->get() to ->first(). Then you will be able to access ID.